# Adding Content to pyqt4 scroll area

Tags: python, pyqt

How can I add content to a scroll area in pyqt4? DO i custom define a widget? For example,
if  i had a array or a list`a =[10,2,2,2,22,3,3,3]`. How should I display teh variable in the scrollbar area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add content to a scroll area, you need to define a new widget and add that to the scroll area - like you would add a widget to a frame. For example:

```
textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(MainWindow)
scrollArea.setWidget(textEdit)
```

Then, you can use textEdit.append() or textEdit.setText() to add the data in the array to the text box in the scroll area. The documentation says it all, really, albeit in C rather than python, but its obvious what you need to do:

```
QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
QImage image("happyguy.png");
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image));

scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark);
scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
```